# What's the logic of sub- in words like suppleo and sufficio?

Tags: classical-latin, etymology, meaning, prefix

The words *suppleo* and *sufficio* both derive from the prefix *sub-* ("under"), in which the 'b' of *sub-* is assimilated into the following consonant. Both these words carry the connotation of "being enough", or "meeting the needs of something or someone". This connotation is absent without the prefix, i.e. *facio* and *pleo* do not have the same connotation, or at least, not to the same degree.

This leads me to wonder how the prefix *sub-* could possibly weigh toward this meaning of "being enough", when paradoxically it means "under". To further complicate things, the opposite is achieved in the English word "suboptimal", which has the implication of something *not* being enough, contrary to words like "supply" and "suffice".

How does *sub-* contribute to this connotation of "being enough", or "meeting the needs of something/someone", in Latin words like *suppleo* and *sufficio*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My semi-educated guess is that one extended sense of *sub-,* "under", is "raised up by something below", especially to ground level—that is, supported or providing support. The English word "support" might itself illustrate this (see below).

Another example is *[suggestum](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=suggestum),* a [raised platform](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/5497/118) such as a stage or pulpit, or a mound, from *[suggero](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=suggero&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059)* < *sub- gero,* "I carry/bear/hold *from below.*"

So, in Latin, *sub*'s core meaning of "under" is often extended or specialized to mean "exerting a force from underneath the object in question", especially a force that helps stabilize it or provide it a ground to stand on.

The idea of "not enough" is itself just another extension of "under", equally as reasonable as "providing a stabilizing force from below." Other extended senses are "pushing down from above" as in *[supprimo](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=supprimo&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059),* "I press down, hold in check", and "sending downward" as in *[subverto](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=subverto&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059),* "I overturn, topple, ruin". The various extended senses often contradict each other, but there's nothing unusual about that. The primary sense of *per* is "through", which is extended sometimes to "thoroughly, fully, greatly" as in *[perplaceo](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dperplaceo),* "I please greatly", and sometimes to "badly, wrongly" as in *[perversus](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=perverto&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059),* "overthrown, ruined, wrong, evil," and perhaps "twisted" (in its English sense as a synonym of "perverse").

[Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/sub-) suggests that *sub-/sup-* might come from older roots *ex-upo-,* meaning "out from under" or perhaps "coming from below"—so *sub-* in this sense of exerting a force from below might even be felt as more fundamental in Latin than merely "under".

Some more examples:

- *[Surgo](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=surgo&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059):* "I arise", "I elevate", from *sub rego.* In an *[insurrectio](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=insurrectio&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059),* "rebellion", *sub*ordinate factions in a society "rise up" to overthrow those who are "on top".
- *[Supporto](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=supporto&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059):* "I bring to a place", especially supplies. Perhaps the metaphor is that of carrying supplies "up" from where they are to where they are needed. I don't know when "support" got its modern meaning of "lifting up, providing a foundation", but it would appear that *sub*'s sense of "exerting force from below" itself exerted a lot of force for a long time (though no longer in modern in English).
- *[Suborno](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=suborno&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059),* "I equip", "I instigate", and *[suggesto](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=suggero&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059),* "I supply", "I advise", "I bring to mind", the verb at the root of *suggestum*, "a raised platform", suggests that *sub-* pairs well with verbs meaning "fill a need". *[Suppleo](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=suppleo&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059)* would seem to echo this notion (and/or *vice versa*). It's easy to think of "filling" a need similarly to "filling" a bucket—filling tending to start from below until the bucket is full, though I know of no specific evidence of this metaphor.
- Another sense of *[sufficio](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=sufficio&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059)* is "I substitute for, I fill in for". Many of the examples in Lewis & Short seem to involve someone from lower in a hierarchy "coming up" to fill a recently vacated higher position. For example, a *[suffectus consul](https://books.google.com/books?id=cyEI5755N2UC&pg=PA364&dq=%22suffectus+consul%22&hl=la&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiG6tXZjurXAhVI5YMKHS_8DUsQuwUIWjAI#v=onepage&q=%22suffectus%20consul%22&f=false)* is a [supplementary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/supplement#Etymology) consul: a vice consul who finishes a consul's term (or perhaps someone appointed to be available to fill in as needed).
- The many senses of *[subicio](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=subicio&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059)* seem to illustrate the many Latin ways of extending the core meaning of *sub-,* generating contradictory senses of the very same word: "I launch downward", "I supply", "I lie beneath", "I place under" (as under a category), "I subject to", "I forge" (substitute worse for better), etc.

Comment: Great answer! The Etymonline page gives a helpful comment: *from Latin preposition sub "under, below, beneath, at the foot of," also "close to, up to, towards;* The sense of *up to* really hits the mark in my two examples, sufficio and suppleo - easy to see how it means "enough". This is also exactly what you say throughout your answer. I am making my own educated guess that yours is correct, or at least, truthful. +1